# select update server for database of android application

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing my first android application. This app is dictionary and uses local SQLite database. Sometimes this database will be updated  by me. So I need to use server for place new database version files. My application  will download new database files   and will replace old data on local places. One way is to use  webhosting for these purposes. But I want ask experts if are there other better options? Perhaps does google play store offer some opportunity for updating database files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the database is really an offline database and the updates don't occur that often, consider bundling the database with your app. When you need to update the database, just update your app. Google Play will host your updated application packages so there's no need for any additional backend infrastructure.

For bundling a database with the app, consider [jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) library.

Comment: Thank You for answer but it is difficult bundling the database with my app update, because part of  database must be editable by users: edit notes and parameters. So I must provide update data in file and my program will downnload and import updated records into database from this file.

Comment: Keep the user data and pre-bundled app data in separate databases.

Comment: In any case, thanks for the proposed solutions